# Is there an easy way to always redirect facebook.com to facebook.com/events/list (Firefox, Osx)

Tags: macos, firefox, internet, browser, url

I often use facebook for communication while working. When I do, I'd  rather not see the facebook newsfeed. Unfortunately it's hard to remember to not go to the frontpage and use facebook.com/messages or facebook.com/events. Is there any way to always redirect from the url https://www.facebook.com/ to https://www.facebook.com/events/list? I use firefox on osx.

I have tried the redirector addon and I'm not able to make it work, not sure if I'm missing something obvious or if it's outdated/buggy.

Comment: How do you get to facebook?  By typing it in?  How about bookmarking it and using that from the bookmark bar, or pinning the facebook event tab?

Comment: yeah, I type it, but if I bookmark it I have to do Ctrl-t (new tab), two letters that match my new bookmark (fv), arrow down and return. If facebook.com (which always ends up being default) requires ctrl t, fa and return. In practice I don't think I can do it if it takes more time, the reptile brain wants results asap.

Answer (score 0):

What I'll do is use the applescript below and launch it with a keyboard shortcut manager:

```
tell application "Firefox"
    open location "https://www.facebook.com/events/list"
end tell
```

I mostly use apptivate for quickly running applescripts with keyboard shortcuts. It's very lightwheight and intuitive. Keyboard maestro is another alternative, probably preferable for power users.

Answer (score 0):

In Redirector settings' panel the pattern should be **Enabled**. Also please try these settings: https://www.facebook.com/ in **Example URL** and **Include Pattern**, and https://www.facebook.com/events/list in **Redirect To**. The **Pattern Type** is Wildcard. Also use **Test pattern** to troubleshoot and get helpful messages.